# Python pandas Dataframe Regex

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I need a RegEx that can detect if the value of a cell in pandas dataframe is on the right date format. The value of the cell should be formatted like this "2018-04-01T06:21:48+00:00".

Thanks,

Peter

Answer (score 0):

I think the following would match the format you are looking for:

```
\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}[T]\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}[+]\d{2}:\d{2}
```

From a high level

- \d{4} matches 4 digit
- \d{2} matches 2 digits
- [T] matches only the 'T' character
- [+] matches only the '+' character

This would not check the validity of the date/time - you will need another function for that.

Give the expression above a try and let us know how you make out.